# How to find a word that starts with a specific character

Tags: python, regex

I want to sort out words which are started with 's' in sentence by python.
Here is my code:

```
import re
text = "I was searching my source to make a big desk yesterday."
m = re.findall(r'[s]\w+', text)
print m
```

But the result of code is :

```
['searching', 'source', 'sk', 'sterday'].
```

How do I write a code about regular expression? Or, is there any method to sort out words?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "I was searching my source to make a big desk yesterday."
>>> re.findall(r'\bs\w+', text)
['searching', 'source']
```

For lowercase and uppercase `s` use: `r'\b[sS]\w+'`

Comment: The ending `'\b'` is not needed with the greedy match proceeding it. Also, I'm guessing that the OP would like to match capital S as well.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski good point, I thought OP might have wanted capital `S` but wasn't sure since OP used `[s]` but I'll add it in as well

Answer (score 13):

I know it is not a regex solution, but you can use `startswith`

```
>>> text="I was searching my source to make a big desk yesterday."
>>> [ t for t in text.split() if t.startswith('s') ]
['searching', 'source']
```

Comment: it's useful way! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to match a single character, you don't need to put it in a character class, so `s` is the same than `[s]`.
2. What you want to find is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). A word boundary `\b` is an anchor that matches on a change from a non word character (`\W`) to a word character (`\w`) or vice versa.

The solution is:

```
\bs\w+
```

this regex will match on a `s` with not a word character before (works also on the start of the string) and needs at least one word character after it. `\w+` is matching all word characters it can find, so no need for a `\b` at the end.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34q92)

Comment: Thank you for detail answer. And adding site will good information

Answer (score 2):

**Lambda style:**

```py
text = 'I was searching my source to make a big desk yesterday.'

list(filter(lambda word: word[0]=='s', text.split()))
```

**Output:**

`['searching', 'source']`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this sample of code and I think it does exactly what you want:

```
import re
text = "I was searching my source to make a big desk yesterday."
m = re.findall (r'\b[s]\w+', text)
print (m)
```

Comment: You do not need to use a class (`[s]`) since you only want to match `s`.
And once you remove this, your answer becomes identical to the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add one small thing here,

Let's say you have a line to find words which starts with `'s'`

```
line = "someone should show something to some@gmail.com"
```

if you write regular expression like,

```
swords = re.findall(r"\b[sS]\w+", line)
```

output will be,

```
['someone','should','show','something','some']
```

But if you modify regular expression to,

```
# use \S instead of \w
swords = re.findall(r"\b[sS]\S+", line)
```

output will be,

```
['someone','should','show','something','some@gmail.com']
```