# "starts with" does not work (python regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
m = 'Film/6702-BRINGING-UP-BABY" da'
```

and the following regax, that tries to find words that start with 'd':

```
 movie = re.findall(r'^d.*', m)
 print(movie)
```

the result is:

```
[]
```

and I can not understand why - there is a match in the string('da'), so why wont it find it?

I an working with pycharm, python 3.6

Comment: The `^`  character means "beginning of the line", not "start of a word". You want the word boundary character `\b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a word that starts with a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440267/how-to-find-a-word-that-starts-with-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using \b as boundary character we can find the words starting with specific character

```
import re
m = 'Film/6702-BRINGING-UP-BABY" da'
movie = re.findall(r'\bd.*', m)
print(movie)
```

output

```
['da']
```