# I tried and I only printed out the letter 's's instead of the words that start with s. I'm not sure how to use the .split() function

Tags: python, if-statement, split, statements, for-comprehension

Use for, `.split()`, and if to create a Statement that will print out words that start with 's':

`st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440267/how-to-find-a-word-that-starts-with-a-specific-character

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
Answer = [word for word in st.split() if word[0] == 's']
print(Answer)
```

Answer (score -1):

Split the list into Strings with `.split()`. Use `" "` as a separator because you want spaces to separate the words.

```
st = "Print only the words that start with s in this sentence"
words = []
for word in st.split(" "):
    if word.startswith("s"):
        words.append(word)

print(words)
```