# How to iterate through a list of strings (i.e a sentence) and check if it has a word starts with a specific word in it?

Tags: python, list, python-re

So the question was to create a for loop which takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and it should return a list of the string which starts with a specifc keyword

Example (the result should be `['python', 'python_one', 'python_two', 'python_three', 'python', 'python_two']`):

```
doc_list = ['welcome to python tutorial', 'you are welcome to python_one tutorial', 'python_two tutorial python_three tutorial', 'hello python', 'hello python_two world']
```

keyword = python

```
import re
doc_list = ['welcome to python tutorial', 'you are welcome to python_one tutorial',  'welcome python_two tutorial python_three tutorial', 'hello python', 'hello python_four world']

output = []
for line in doc_list:
    y = re.search(r' (python.*?) ', line)
    if y: output.append(y.group(1))
    
print(output)
```

The result i get is

```
['python', 'python_one', 'python_two', 'python_four']
```

Here python_three is missing since my code is ignoring the multiple occurance of python in each string of sentance.

Comment: The *str* object has a built-in *startswith()* with function which you'll find useful. You don't really need *re* for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python) Also: [How to find a word that starts with a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440267/how-to-find-a-word-that-starts-with-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
import re

doc_list = [
    "welcome to python tutorial",
    "you are welcome to python_one tutorial",
    "welcome python_two tutorial python_three tutorial",
    "hello python",
    "hello python_two world",
]

out = []
for doc in doc_list:
    out.extend(re.findall(r"\bpython\S*", doc))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
  "python", 
  "python_one", 
  "python_two", 
  "python_three", 
  "python", 
  "python_two"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Iterate over the doc_list, split each element (sentence) into its component words then check each word using *startswith()*.

```
doc_list = ['welcome to python tutorial', 'you are welcome to python_one tutorial',  'welcome python_two tutorial python_three tutorial', 'hello python', 'hello python_four world']
result = []
for sentence in doc_list:
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.startswith("python"):
            result.append(word)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['python', 'python_one', 'python_two', 'python_three', 'python', 'python_four']
```

Comment: It is possible to pass a variable to startswith.

Comment: @Milind I am grateful for the edification